# How to create a function that uses up all malloced memory

Tags: c, linux

I want to make a function that I can stick before the stuff in a test main and it will use up all the space for malloc (causing future allocations to fail). The problem is that once the function finishes everything seems to get freed...

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void    breakmalloc(void)
{
    int *i;
    int n;

    n = 1;
    i = &n;
    while (n)
    {
        while (i)
        {
            i = malloc(n);
            if (i)
                n = n + n;
        }
        n = n / 2;
        i = &n;
    }
}
```

it exits the function when I test it so it would seem that all of the space has been used up but as soon as the function finishes I can then malloc other stuff in future functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some operating systems such an Linux perform **optimistic memory allocation**.  That means that whatever memory is returned by `malloc` and family is not immediately allocated and therefore not necessarily available.  So even if you were to allocate 100GB of memory `malloc` would still probably return non-NULL.

The memory won't actually get allocated until you use it.  So to force it, you should `memset` the block.

```
i = malloc(n);
if (i) {
    memset(i, 0, n);
    n = n + n;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if the test result using your trick handled green/red correctly since memory is exhausted. If your code call malloc to allocate memory, and you want test it. I guess you've better to use simple trick.

```
#ifdef TEST
#  undef malloc
#  define malloc(x) (NULL)
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void breakmalloc(void) 
{
    char *buff = NULL;
    int size = 1024;
    while (1) {
        buff = (char *)malloc(size);
        if (buff) {
            memset(buff, 1, size); //must use it, or optimized by system
        } else {
            printf("memory insufficient!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

try like this